# Excel - Sum the String Value

Tags: excel, sum

I'm making a timetable for our colleague, I have a table as following,
Value A = 4 / Value B = 4 Value F = 8

and I need to know the amount between Mon to Fri amount, not sure what is the exact function that I should use.

I tried this:
=SUM(IF(B6:AE6="F",VALUE("8"),VALUE("4")))
But is not working

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>
    Mon
  </td>
    <td>
    Tue
  </td>
    <td>
    Wed
  </td>
    <td>
    Thu
  </td>
  <td>
    Fri
  </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    A
  </td>
    <td>
    A
  </td>
    <td>
    F
  </td>
    <td>
    B
  </td>
  <td>
    B
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following array-formula should help you. Array-formula means that you enter it with

> Ctrl+Shift+Enter

You do not enter the { } brackets manually, they will appear automatically.

```
{=SUM(--($A$2:$E$2="A")*4,--($A$2:$E$2="B")*4,--($A$2:$E$2="F")*8)}
```

The values for Monday to Friday are in A2:E2 in this example.

[image]

Comment: I try this code
{=SUM(--($A$2:$E$2="A")*4,--($A$2:$E$2="B")*4,--($A$2:$E$2="F")*8)}

but seems not working.

Comment: Did you write this code `=SUM(--($A$2:$E$2="A")*4,--($A$2:$E$2="B")*4,--($A$2:$E$2="F")*8)` and then hit the keys Ctrl+Shift+Enter? The brackets around the formula are not something you add manually.

Comment: Also, what does that formula return for you?

Comment: yes, use this code, but when to hit "Ctrl+Shift+Enter"?  when select this code?

Comment: You usually type in a formula and then hit Enter, right? Instead of Enter, hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code:

```
=4*COUNTIF(B6:AE6,"A")+4*COUNTIF(B6:AE6,"B")+8*COUNTIF(B6:AE6,"F")
```

[image]